# Can't create Model by View and Partialview updated using ajax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

First of all sorry for my English.

**My problem:**

I've a table called Inspeccio and a related table called Criteris. The relation is ManyToMany so I've the table CriterisInspeccio.

I've a Model for these tables with the same name.

When I want to create a Inspeccio there's a Dropdownlist for different types of Inspeccio.

[image]

When I change the value of this Dropdownlist a list of Criteris is updated using ajax.
[image]

But when I submit the form the controller receive the InspeccioViewModel without the Criteris of the list.

**The code:**

**InspecciosController:**

```
  // GET: Inspeccios/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.IdTipusInspeccio = new SelectList(db.TipusInspeccio, "IdTipusInspeccio", "Tipus");
        InspeccioViewModel inspeccioViewModel = new InspeccioViewModel();
        return View(inspeccioViewModel);
    }

[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(InspeccioViewModel inspeccioViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Inspeccio inspeccio = InspeccioHelper.ToInspeccio(inspeccioViewModel);
            db.Inspeccio.Add(inspeccio);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(inspeccioViewModel);
    }

    public ActionResult CriterisSegonsTipusInspeccio(int idTipusInspeccio)
    {
        ICollection<CriterisInspeccioAssignatsViewModel> criteris = CriterisSegonsTipusInspeccioFalse(idTipusInspeccio);
        return PartialView("CriterisInspeccioAssignatsViewModel", criteris);
    }
```

**Create view:**

```
    @model Inspeccions.ViewModels.InspeccioViewModel

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }


    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Inspeccio</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Clau, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Clau, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Clau, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataCaducitat, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataCaducitat, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control date-picker" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataCaducitat, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Data, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Data, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control date-picker" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Data, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hora, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hora, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Hora, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Expedient, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Expedient, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Expedient, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdTipusInspeccio, "Tipus", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("IdTipusInspeccio", null, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdTipusInspeccio, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
            </div>
        </div>

         <div class="form-group" id="criteris"></div>

        <div>
            <br />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default"/>
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>
}



<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Tornar al llistat d'inspeccions", "Index")
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#IdTipusInspeccio").change(function () {
            var categoryId = $("#IdTipusInspeccio").val();
            $("#criteris").load('@(Url.Action("CriterisSegonsTipusInspeccio", "Inspeccios", null, Request.Url.Scheme))?idTipusInspeccio=' + categoryId);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**PartialView CriterisInspeccioAssignatsViewModel:**

```
  @model ICollection<Inspeccions.ViewModels.CriterisInspeccioAssignatsViewModel>
@using Inspeccions.Helpers

@foreach (var criteri in Model)
{

    <div class="form-horizontal">
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(criter => criteri.Titol)
                </dt>

                <dd>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(criter => criteri.Titol)
                </dd>

                <dt>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(criter => criteri.Descripcio)
                </dt>

                <dd>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(criter => criteri.Descripcio)
                </dd>
            </dl>
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.HiddenFor(criter => criteri.IdCriteri, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(criter => criteri.IdCriteri, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(criter => criteri.IdCriteri, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            @if (@Html.Action() == "Create" || @Html.Action() == "Edit" || @Html.Action() == "CriterisSegonsTipusInspeccio")
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(criter => criteri.Assignada, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.EditorFor(criter => criteri.Assignada)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(criter => criteri.Assignada, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }

            @if (@Html.Action() == "Details")
            {
                <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                    <dt>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(criter => criteri.Assignada)
                    </dt>

                    <dd>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(criter => criteri.Assignada)
                    </dd>
                </dl>
            }
        </div>
        <hr />
}
```

If I use it without ajax, having the Criteris fixed it works...

I've search it in Google and I can't find a solution for me.

Can you help me please?

Lot of thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the solution!

The problem comes from

```
public ActionResult CriterisSegonsTipusInspeccio(InspeccioViewModel inspeccioViewModel)
{
    ICollection<CriterisInspeccioAssignatsViewModel> criteris = CriterisSegonsTipusInspeccioFalse(inspeccioViewModel.IdTipusInspeccio);
    inspeccioViewModel.CriterisInspeccioViewModel = criteris;
    return PartialView("CriterisInspeccioAssignatsViewModel", inspeccioViewModel);
}
```

It have to receive the Model :)